# Trouble loading images in IntelliJ Java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This is probably a really basic question, but I have been unable to find it answered anywhere else.

I am having trouble getting some GIFs to show up in my IntelliJ project, and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. The folder with the GIFs in it is located in the same directory as my class file. That directory is inside another directory that has been designated a sources folder, and my compiler resource patter settings look like this:

!?*.java;!?*.form;!?*.class;!?*.groovy;!?*.scala;!?*.flex;!?*.kt;!?*.clj;*.gif

What's even more weird is that the images display just fine if I point the program at the full address of the folder (/Users/rrtoboz/IdeaProjects/First/src/com/rrtoboz/chaptertwelve/cardset-oxymoron), but do not display if I point it at just /cardset-oxymoron. I've been told it's bad design to include the full address like that, so I've been trying to get it to work the other way and having no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you display images?

Comment: `String cardset = "cardset-oxymoron";
String s = String.format("%s/%02d%c.gif", cardset, rank, c);
images[suit][rank] = new ImageIcon(s).getImage();`
 
So s uses cardset the generate the file name of a specific image, then it is loaded into the array using s, then displayed using this code: 
 
`public void drawCard(Graphics g, int suit, int rank, double x, double y) {
 Image image = images[suit][rank];
 g.drawImage(image, 
      (int)(x * cardWidth), 
      (int)(y * cardHeight),
      null);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
new ImageIcon(AClassInTheChaptertwelvePackage.class.getResource(s));
```